# CSS Radio Button not selecting or displaying correct image in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using css custom styling for radio buttons which work in firefox and chrome. However, in IE8 the image is not displaying the checked tick and is just displaying the unticked image. Also, if I select an option to change the radio button, nothing happens. This is driving me nuts and would appreciate some help as to how to overcome this. Thanks

[image]

css code

```
input[type=radio].css-checkbox {
    display:none;
    }

input[type=radio].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
    padding-left:20px;
    height:15px; 
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:15px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-size:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;

    }

input[type=radio].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
    background-position: 0 -15px;
    }

label.css-label {
    background-image:url(../../images/tick2.png);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    }
```

html input sample

```
<input id="service1a" name="service" type="radio" class="css-checkbox" value="Standard" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: `input[type=checkbox]:checked` is not supported by IE8 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked

Comment: @Paulie so what is the workaround for IE8? Thanks

Comment: @SW4 Can you use images with fiddle? Thanks

Comment: To solve this for IE8, you would need Javascript/ Jquery.

Comment: @Paulie what would you suggest. I have tried selectivizr.js latest version and although it displays the images, it still does nothing when a radio button is clicked. Thanks

Comment: That's a subject of another question I suspect.